# Anime for colorblind people?

Tags: anime-production

Is there any anime created for colorblind people?

In general anime productions have a strong use of colors to increase the dramatic effect, but colorblind people miss it and sometimes lose track of important parts of the history.

Image example (not exactly from an anime, but...)

- [here is the original image](http://www.wall321.com/thumbnails/detail/20130124/redheads%20ice%20cream%20long%20hair%20komatsu%20pink%20hair%20maburaho%20anime%20strawberries%20anime%20girls%20children%201_www.wall321.com_33.jpg)
- in [this site](http://www.vischeck.com/vischeck/vischeckURL.php) you can simulate how it looks to a colorblind... just select the previous link, and paste it there

(and just a clarification: it's not exactly to me :) ... it's for a small one who we just found that can't correctly see some colors. And, also, in the site I mentioned above, I found a "daltonize" algorithm that changes colors so that colorblind people have a bit more contrast on the colors they miss, so it improves the image to them)

Thanks :)

Comment: read the manga.  It's normally better than anime even without the color

Comment: @woliveirajr There are varying degrees of color blindness, can you be a little more specific in your context? Picture examples would help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, lets take a [simulated look](http://www.colblindor.com/coblis-color-blindness-simulator/) of how the following image is viewed by different people:

**Normal Color Vision**

[image: Normal]

**Red Blind (Protanopia)**

[image: Red-Blind]

**Green-Blind (Deuteranopia)**

[image: Green-Blind]

**Blue-Blind (Tritanopia)**

[image: Blue-Blind]

**Red-Weak (Protanomaly)**

[image: Red-Weak]

**Green-Weak (Deuteranomaly)**

[image: Green-Weak]

**Blue-Weak (Tritanomaly)**

[image: Blue-Weak]

**Monochromacy (Achromatopsia)**

[image: Monochromacy]

**Blue Cone (Monochromacy)**

[image: Blue Cone]

Protanopia and Deuteranopia are the [most common types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness) of colorblindness.

As you see, the experiences of these color-blind viewers are not inhibited by their condition. Though a particular image or scene might not have as much of an impact on a normal user, they are still able to enjoy the other aspects of anime such as the writing and dialog, voice-acting, most importantly the animation.

There might not necessarily be anime for blind people, because anime is intended to be marketed to a wider audience, usually for recreational purposes.

Typically anime productions don't factor accessibility concerns of color blind viewers in the budget due to the extra costs required, since most of the profit from an anime production is from disc sales.

Color blind people usually rely on the settings on their computer (using a specific color profiles, "color blind" modes in games) or television (color adjustments on the TV) to adjust their visual experience.

Rarely does color play a major plot and history of an anime series, but if it does, the change is usually significant (e.g. Victorique's hair in *Gosick*), noticeable, and/or emphasized by the story and dialogue.

The color setting is only a small piece of the anime puzzle. Even without it, you might be missing small details, you'll still be able to get the big picture.

Comment: Well, i, just look at the pictures, the kind poster before me posted and ask yourself, if you could not enjoy anime like that. I know people who are colourblind and still love anime and think they are colourful, since there are, like listed above, a lot of types of colourblindness.
And i would personally prefer the Blue Cone "style" towards the "normal" one.
;)